# Integrated Windows Authentication on Firefox 101.0 64-bit against adfs server?

Tags: windows-10, firefox

I was reading about how to get Firefox to login to an adfs server (probably via SAML proxy?), so that I don't have to type my password every time I access a particular URL that always asks with an HTTP AUTH dialog box for my sign in information.

The ADFS server it appears to authenticate against is something like: `adfs.xxxxxx.tld`

and the actual website is `http://xxxxx.easyvista.com/`

I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication#Supported_web_browsers)(1) that if I set some of the configuration settings within Firefox I should be able to do this.

I also read that [here](https://help.hcltechsw.com/domino/10.0.1/secu_enabling_iwa_in_firefox.html)(2).

I set the domain of that in the settings as specified in link (2) using the address of the adfs.

Additionally, I went into the settings for firefox and checked off the following:

[image]

But I still get the HTTP AUTH prompt.

Is there anything else I need to set to make this work?

Comment: Is your Microsoft Account or your Active Directory domain [work or school] account linked to the account to the website in question? If does the account appear in Settings? Is this account the same account you use to log into the device?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't understand the first question, I don't know how to link it to the website in question; but I do know that the URL seems to redirect to the adfs server when I try to login to that site.

What settings?

It is the same account I use to login to the device.

Comment: Let me ask the question a different way, does the website your asking about support ADFS authentication,

Comment: @Ramhound I'm sure it does because the HTTP AUTH displays when you access the site; also, if I'm on the VPN it gives me the adfs webpage login instead.  I'm not sure what causes it.

Comment: I assume this website is part of a work function.  To answer your question the ADFS account should be listed in Settings, in order for Windows to remember that account, that doesn't necessarily mean you won't ever been asked to authenticate that account obviously.

Comment: @Ramhound Which settings?

Comment: Settings is a UWP application that displays all sorts of settings, the setting I would be interested in know about, would be which accounts you have linked to your profile.  Specifically if the account you are authenticated the website is linked.  **Which was the very first question I asked.** I am still waiting on the answer to that question.

Comment: @Ramhound Which of these applications within settings do you wish for me to open?

`ms-settings:????`

Comment: I cannot help you, if you provide the screenshot, be sure to ping me otherwise I cannot help you.

Comment: @Ramhound Screenshot of what exactly?

Comment: Accounts within Settings